# Check box doesn't work in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello all I have a autocomplete search box that searches the data correctly. This is how it looks like

When I click on check box I want this to be added to the database table through an ajax call but no luck.
Below is my code

```
$("#srch").keyup(function () {
                    var s = $("#srch").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checkmenu.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {s: s},
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#sresult").fadeIn("slow");
                            $("#sresult").html(response);
                        }

                    });
                });
```

Above is the code that searches the item (Working fine). and shows me the result that's in picture attached

This is how its been fetched

```
if (isset($_POST['s'])) {
if (!$_POST['s'] == "") {
    $q = mysqli_query($link, "select * from menuitems where mitem like '%" . $_POST['s'] . "%' order by mitem") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $m = "";
    if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $m = '<div class="col s12" id="box">
                <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cluname" id="mitem" value="' . $row["mitem"] . '">
          <p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cluname" id="test5" name="mitem[]" value="' . $row["mitem"] . '" />
  <label for="test5"><b>' . $row['mitem'] . '</b> </label>
</p>
        </div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <input type="hidden" name="iid[]" id="iid" value="' . $row["id"] . '">
      <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user"  value="' . $_SESSION["u"] . '">
      <input type="hidden" name="tno" id="tno" value="' . $_SESSION["tno"] . '">          


      </div> 
      <div class="col s12 m6 l4">Rs.' . $row['rate'] . '/-</div></div>
      <div class="col s12">
      <br>
      </div>';
            echo $m;
        }
    }
}}
```

now when I click on the check box it doesn't add the data in the database.
to do that I have following code.

```
$(".cluname").on("change", function () {
                    var ss = "Yes";
                    var insert=[];
                    var user = $("#user").val();
                    var tno = $("#tno").val();
                    var qty = $("#qty").val();
                    $(".cluname").each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked")){
                            insert.push($(this).val());
                        }
                    });
                    insert = insert.toString();
                    console.log(insert);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checkmenu.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {insert:insert, ss: ss, user: user, tno: tno, qty: qty},
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log("Success");
                            $("#suc").show();
                            $("#suc").html(response);
                            setTimeout("$('#suc').fadeOut();", 1500);
                            $("#ro").show();

                        }, error: function () {
                            alert("Error");
                            console.log("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong? as I am new to ajax.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7ZL6.png)

My network tab says 200 OK

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLTcM.png)

Comment: Can you try to visit your `Network` tab then doing the same process and check if there are any response.

Comment: Did you check if the change event is called and the ajax call is made? If the call is made then check the call header and see if PHP insert method which is responsible for saving data to the DB is executed.

Comment: No Response.  I checked that as well :(

Comment: change event is not getting called I guess. Is it because I wrote <input type=""checkbox"> at checkmenu.php?

Comment: try putting the code in your php file. Maybe the event isn't able to bind since the element doesn't yet exist in your main file

Comment: That didn't work too

Comment: Could you try to debug and see if the expected data is being parsed? Could you try to echo your SQL, and then alert(html); in your AJAX success function (so that the SQL command gets put into the alert). That should be a fast way to see if the SQL command is structured correctly.